# Error returned when trying to run a basic function in dart

Tags: function, dart

I'm new to dart (coming from a python background), and I'm struggling to make a function work. I've created the following function:

```
void main() {
  int number = 22;

  Function evenChecker(int number) {
    if ((number%2) == 0) {
      print('$number is even');
    } else {
      print('$number is odd');
    }
  }
}
```

but is get the following error:

```
 Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'Function' doesn't allow null.
bin/hello_dart_project.dart:4
 - 'Function' is from 'dart:core'.
```

Additionally, if anyone has any suggestions about a good dart learning resource, I'd highly appreciate the advice.
^

Comment: Where have you seen that you should prefix methods with `Function` in Dart?

Comment: The syntax for function declarations in Dart is `ReturnType FunctionName(ParameterList)`.  `Function evenChecker(int number)` declares a function that *returns* a `Function`.  Since your function returns nothing, it should be just `void evenChecker(int number)`.

Comment: A good starting place for learning Dart is the Tour: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour. There are many free courses on youtube if you search "Dart Tutorial" as well. If you're learning Flutter, take a look at the Flutter Learning page: https://flutter.dev/learn

Answer (score 1):

Unlike Python or JavaScript, there is no keyword to define functions in dart. Instead, we declare functions by starting with their return type:

```
void evenChecker(...) {...}
^^^^
// This is the return type. "void" means "returns the value null" or "doesn't return anything"
```